# Espionage by CRT mirroring

Tags: crt

Quite a few decades ago (either late 70's or early 80's), I vaguely remember seeing on TV a demonstration of, what would now be called, *mirroring* of a CRT screen, that was over 30 meters away, *without* the use of any cables, fibre optics, wires or what have you - this was "through the air" (as described at the time). Hence, the output of the computer that was connected to the CRT could be seen, even though the "hacker" was not at the actual computer's console.

The TV article raised fears about spying, Soviet espionage, etc. - as was usual in those days.

Irrespective of the geo-politics behind the potential for espionage (involving the misuse of this technology 40 years ago), how was this mirroring actually achieved back in the day<sup>1</sup>?

I haven't been able to find a recording of the clip yet, but I will update this question when I do.

#### Addendum

Thanks to [Michael's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388048/espionage-by-crt-mirroring#comment945835_388048), the video in question is this: [TEMPEST - Protection from Computer Eavesdropping ~ BBC Tomorrow's World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYYm9Lin8X4)... which sort of has the answer in the video title!

---

<sup>1</sup> Please note that I have no desire to reproduce this effect today, using either CRTs or with flat screen technology. At the risk of repeating myself - I merely wish to know how it was achieved back then.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the [Van Eck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking), which I believed was "implemented" only fictionally by Neal Stephenson in his Cryptonomicon. But apparently (according to Wiki) some experimental equipment was indeed constructed.

Comment: Oh, really? So it was a very early example of *fake news*? Interesting... Thanks

Comment: No, not necessarily. It might be my lack of information. But 30m sounds like fake.

Comment: Are you asking what you would use to transmit the video signal going to a local screen and remotely control another screen with the same image?

Comment: @Andyaka I guess it's more like "what would I need to detect in order to reconstruct an image from remote CRT display".

Comment: @Andyaka - yes, I believe so, *without* the use of a hard connection, 40 years ago. I have clarified the question. Thanks.

Comment: Surreptitious remote login is what you might be talking about and I think its off-topic here (and probably illegal too).

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Careful though, I don't want to know how I would do it *now*, I want to know how it was done back then. This is a historical question.

Comment: @Andyaka - Sorry if I was unclear. It certainly isn't off-topic as it would have something to do with electro-magnetism, or electro-magnetic signals (unless you think that SE.Physics is more of a suitable site), and not about remote login. There was no logging in (remote or otherwise) - The CRT image was captured (somehow) upon a remote CRT. I wish that I could find a copy of the video, as it would make the description a lot clearer.

Comment: Go the public library. Check-out a copy of Cryptonomicon. Read the section about Van Eck phreaking. That is as close as you are going to get to a description of how it works.

Comment: These days no one is using CRT, they are extinct.

Comment: Old military equipment (the one of the most interest for spying on) is still heavily using it.

Comment: there's a defcon talk where the presenter uses an SDR to capture the emi and show it

Comment: It's not fictional, and it's been demonstrated well beyond 30ml: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking

Comment: I've seen, first hand, home computers of that era leak enough out of their RF modulators to be received by TV tuners at a distance of about 30 feet.

Comment: You are missing the TEMPEST keyword. Maybe the following video is a close match of the contents you remember of? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjIhS_JQ80k (Or BBC's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYYm9Lin8X4) Eavesdropping on Keyboard is also demonstrated here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFWgIAgMtiA. In the late 90s the program “TEMPEST for Elisa” was a popular demonstration of the principle, turning the CRT into a radio emitter. See it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-O1QWWmVmg

Comment: @MichaelLeBarbierGrünewald - Fantastic! Thank you, yes, it was the Tomorrow's World episode. I have updated my question.

Comment: @StephenKitt - After doing some further googling around the topic, I came across [your comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/spying-on-old-computer-monitor-rf-signals#comment19266_7018) on Retro. Would you care to post it as an answer here, as it seems very relevant and contains additional information (and the second link) that is not included in any, as yet, posted answers?

Comment: @Greenonline Is there any relationship between the two questions, or did they just happen to be posted around the same time?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - Not sure, I've only just seen his comment this morning, via google, after having a root around stuff thrown up by Michel's answer.

Comment: The BBC (and likely other broadcasters) used to detect the channel you were watching, the floor (room even) the TV was in and if you were using a colour TV receiver from basic equipment in their van by sniffing the colour sub-carrier re-radiation from your set to determine your taxes.  The basics were well understood and video could have been decoded easily with some more effort.

Comment: @KalleMP -  I heard that the dreaded *TV detector van* of the 70's/80's/90's, whilst it existed, was actually a fake, and that they actually relied on (1) Records of sales of TV (where an address was given at the point of sale); (2) Addresses that had at one point had a TV license, and then did not (as it had not been renewed) and; (3) the assumption that *everyone* had a telly, and that any address that did not have a license, then had their door knocked upon. I am not sure *how true* that rumour is. I don't think that that is the case anymore though - although I wouldn't take a gamble on it!

Comment: I haven't really delved into it, but if I put my RTL-SDR antenna near my LCD screen and tune to a certain frequency I am able to receive different-sounding signals depending on what's on the screen.

Comment: @Greenonline There was nothing illegal about *owning* a TV without a license. To bring a prosecution, the BBC had to produce evidence that the TV was being *used* to receive their broadcasts - and not for some other purpose, e.g. it had been converted into an oscilloscope. Just "knocking on doors" wasn't enough.

Comment: If you want some research papers about the CRT and LCD methods, this publication list might be interesting for you: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/publications.html

Comment: @alephzero in South Africa during the days of active TV licence management (more haphazard of late) if you wanted to own but not use a TV you had to have it __sealed__ where they would bag it and tape it with their sealing tape and then put a frangible sticker over the tape, same with CB and Ham radio gear that you did not have a licence for.  They could inspect at a whim but I never heard of them doing so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching a bit more thanks to [Eugene's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388048/espionage-by-crt-mirroring?noredirect=1#comment945638_388048), I found this, where it states it can be done from hundred meters, even without very expensive equipment.

See [Wim van Eck's legacy](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/wim-van-ecks-legacy/).

Fragment:

> Oscillating electric currents within your monitor produce radio
>   frequency electromagnetic radiation (EMR) that correlate to what the
>   monitor displays. In cooperation with the BBC in February 1985, van
>   Eck was able to confirm through experimental proof of concept that
>   this form of electronic eavesdropping is possible from distances of up
>   to several hundred meters.
>
> While such danger to information security was already known at the
>   time of van Eck's paper, it was generally believed that such
>   eavesdropping was prohibitively difficult for amateurs — meaning, for
>   the most part, non-military personnel — and would require extremely
>   expensive, specialized, restricted equipment. Wim van Eck's research
>   showed that it can be accomplished with nothing that isn't readily
>   available on the open market — that, in fact, "In the case of
>   eavesdropping on a video display unit, this can be a normal TV
>   broadcast receiver."

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it refers to Van Eck and his effect, who is, in a roundabout way, mentioned in the video. Van Eck is associated with the [Doctor Neher laboratories in Holland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYYm9Lin8X4&t=123), as his research paper, [Electromagnetic Radiation from Video
Display Units: An Eavesdropping Risk?](http://cryptome.org/jya/emr.pdf) even includes the Doctor Neher lab's address at the top. The research paper is the actual answer that I was looking for, whereas TEMPEST seems to be the method to counter the effect. Thanks to *everyone* for their answers.

Comment: @Greenonline thanks for the question, remark and accepting the answer. I didn't know about him before and he's from the same country as me :-).

Answer (score 11):

You could start reading [here](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/privacy/introduction-tempest-981) for a reasonable coverage of the problem.

I worked on an early color CRT (Data General CRT terminal) that included Tempest rating. There we encoded the signals to the guns (grids) from the motherboard to the neck of the tube, decoding them right on the CRT neck. The tube was encased in extensive shielding.

Update: While some make fun of this potential compromise in the comments, there were serious implications. You don't need to RX/decode a whole screen. The biggest problem was with logon screens. Well documented and easily discerned. you only need decode user names and potentially password. I do remember that we altered our logon screens to never echo the password in any way. Many, particularly Unix based systems of the time used to flash the character you typed and then backspace and overwrite it with an Asterisk. Very poor security.

Comment: Yep, nice article, thanks, +1. The idea was barely applicable to black-and-white monitors, where the transmission is over a single channel, line-by-line, and amplified by electronic gun of a CRT, and resembles broadcast modulation schema. But if you have three differential HDMI lines with packet-based encoding, be my guest to sense this from even 10 cm.

Comment: I fall to see how `differential HDMI lines with packet-based encoding` can have *any* relevance to a question about technology from 40 years ago

Comment: @Greenonline, *"can have any relevance to a question about technology from 40 years ago"* - then remove all references to "geo-politics behind the potential for espionage", and you will have no mentioning  of HDMI or Wi-Fi.

Comment: @AliChen - done. Hopefully it is clearer than it was.

Answer (score 9):

The pixel signal current ( image raster display) can be radiated easily in CRT type displays in uV /m field strength and is tested by EMI “Tempest Level screening” criteria much lower than FCC Class B.

I briefly observed such testing hidden by security drop sheets when I was doing similar tests to magnetic HDD’s on interface cables at a Burroughs test faculty in Paoli, PA, USA in the early 80’s.

Comment: I can verify that electric field coupling from a CRT is possible. An open-end oscilloscope probe rendered an obvious video signal from the next lab over. Probably not much more than 1-2 m away, through a wall. But with a little high-Z amplifier, a video monitor on my side of the wall could have rendered a duplicated version. In that era, Ch 3, or Ch 4 video modulators were often used to drive a standard TV, and could be more vulnerable to remote sensing.

Answer (score 8):

[It would appear to still be possible](https://github.com/martinmarinov/TempestSDR) with modern(er) monitors.

[These folks give intructions](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/tempestsdr-a-sdr-tool-for-eavesdropping-on-computer-screens-via-unintentionally-radiated-rf) for getting the software from the first link to run under Windows.

They mention capturing video from a monitor with DVI, and another with HDMI. Not sure if they are capturing signals from the monitor or from the cable.

The priciple is the same as way back when, it's just easier and cheaper using an SDR dongle and some software.

Back in the day, you had to feed the captured signal to a modified monitor similar to the one you were spying on.

These days, the software makes images on the fly and displays them on your monitor.

[This appears to be a recording of the software in action.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=mBJ6uQZsF9c)

---

Tempest was FUN.

Way back in the stone ages, I was in the US Air Force - draftsman in civil engineering.

The stuff we worked on was all classified - our office was literally a safe with thick steel door with a dial combination lock.

When the Major heading our section needed to present status charts at a briefing, I would be tasked with making the overhead projector slides on the computer.

Since the information was rated "secret," it could only be done on a tempest rated computer and the slides printed on a tempest rated printer.

We had one of each, but no software that could both a) run on the computer and b) talk to the printer.

I ended up writing a program to make the slides on the computer, then got out the printer manual and figured out how to directly drive it.  My program rasterized the slide from the screen and sent the individual commands to fire the pins on the dot matrix printer - and shift the ink ribbon up and down to make the different colors.

The base photography section had good software and printers.  But, their computers and printers weren't tempest rated, their offices weren't secure enough, and they didn't have the security clearance needed to see the stuff on the slides.  So, I got to make a stack of ugly slides for every briefing.

And, being the lowest ranked guy in the office, I got stuck flipping slides during the briefings, too.  Rear projection.  To this day, I can read mirrored text almost as fast as I can read normal text.

Comment: That's pretty cool I must admit. Never was interested in SDR, now I am.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, this generally refers to (an instance of) [van Eck phreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking), *i.e.* eavesdropping on electromagnetic radiation. In the case of CRTs, the radiation being eavesdropped on is emitted by the high-voltage, high-frequency circuitry which drives the electron gun; from that signal, all you need to do is re-inject synchronisation pulses to be able to reconstruct the display. This works best with simple images, such as low-resolution TV screens, text displays, or (as others have mentioned) login screens — and any login screen which displays any information at all about the password (including asterisks etc.) is vulnerable since timing is often sufficient to reconstruct a password. If you can “lock on” to one simple screen, you might be able to keep on watching even when the image becomes not so simple.

The advent of SDR has made this much more approachable, and there have been a number of successful experiments on a variety of targets; see [rtl-sdr.com](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/tag/tempest/) for some examples. Anything which leaks electromagnetic radiation at a specific frequency can conceivably be eavesdopped; this includes for example DVI cables with poor shielding, so LCD displays can in some cases be vulnerable even though you’d expect the screens themselves not to suffer from the same issues as CRTs in this respect. CPUs themselves generate electromagnetic radiation which can in some cases be listened to and used to reconstruct data [such as AES keys](https://www.fox-it.com/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/Tempest_attacks_against_AES.pdf). (If you control the CPU itself, you can use this to exfiltrate data.)

Radiation in the visible spectrum can also be used — if variations in luminosity can be detected, even indirectly, that can be enough to reconstruct an image. See [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7019/79) on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) for details.

It’s also worth reading up on [TEMPEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)), which is intended to help build systems which are resistant to this type of attack.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it was the van Eck effect that was portrayed in the video. The other answer that you refer to is interesting, but I don't think that it would have worked in a van parked outside the TV studio, or even in another room with a wall between, thus preventing a *line-of-sight* solution.

Comment: Yes, the video shows van Eck phreaking; I thought I’d mention the other answer for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

I actually demonstrated this back in the day, a relatively broadband receiver, a decent yagi and I used the fact that the telly (and often vcrs) back then had a field rate synchronized to the mains to make field sync a non issue (Well once I had figured out that I was on a different phase to the transmitter....).

IIRC my set was operating somewhere above the 70cms band, with about 4MHz of bandwidth and a crude log amp doing the demodulation.

The term was Tempest back then after the military screening development project.

RF side channels are STILL a popular game, used for everything from attacking smart cards (Arguably a power side channel attack, but whatever) to going after crypto keys on laptops (The emissions tell you about the processor C state transitions which can be turned into a timing attack), to the really fun one, going after wireless keyboards by timing the bursts of RF to tell when people kit keys (Turns out this can be used to decode what keys are being hit).

SDRs with wideband demodulators are a hoot for this stuff.

Comment: Yes, it is well known that most (if not all) USB-RF keyboards lack of security, even without timing the RF bursts, https://www.wired.com/2016/07/radio-hack-steals-keystrokes-millions-wireless-keyboards/

Comment: Well yea, granted, but you can even do it to WIRED keyboards quite often.

Comment: Yes, many LS wired keyboard are allowed to have unshielded cables, so they might "emanate" as hell. Symmetrically, they are susceptible as hell to external EMI.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to radiofrequency eavesdropping, it is possible to spy on a CRT by watching the optical brightness at a high sampling rate. See this paper: [Optical Time-Domain Eavesdropping Risks of CRT Displays](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ieee02-optical.pdf)

This works for CRTs because as the electron gun scans the screen, only a small point is very bright (and the rest of the screen is fading away quickly). Capturing the average brightness of the entire screen is similar to capturing just the brightness of the spot pointed at by the electron gun.

For modern displays like LCDs, the entire picture is lit all the time, so this technique won't work because you would only get the average brightness of the entire screen.

Comment: If you could see the screen why would you not just read it?

Comment: Interesting, whilst this was not the method employed in the video, it sounds similar (if not the same) as the second method in [Stephen's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388048/espionage-by-crt-mirroring#388176). Thanks.

Comment: @Transistor - presumably the idea is that if you couldn't see the screen directly, but say see a room lit by it, by sampling that at high speed you could recover the image.  In case you wonder what the folks across the way are watching on TV...

Answer (score -4):

Regarding the first part of the OP question, a BW analog monitor signaling is essentially a demodulated broadcast signal, so it should be possible to extract it from parasitic CRT emissions with some effort, and re-condition it with some fidelity, especially if it was an early no-gray-scale binary monitor.

However, from "geo-political and espionage" angle of this question, this is an outbreak of Cold-War era paranoia. Yes, there was a broader idea that, by observing electromagnetic unintentional emission from computer equipment from a distance, it would be possible to reconstruct the essence of transmitted information.

From technical point, we all know that one has to work very hard to get proper direct connection to data transmission lines, get low-noise probes, insanely priced protocol analyzers, and even after all that you can't really understand what's going on. It takes many directed simplified experiments and test patterns to differentiate any essential byte patterns from scrambling/packet wrapping etc. Even after that the data are usually formatted in proprietary structures. Again, it is extremely difficult even with direct attachment, at volt-level signals and nearly eliminated noise, while remotely one can get the signal at microvolt-level only.

From physics and mathematical perspective, the radiated emission is a linear superposition of weak remainders of wave patterns emitted from many location of electronic equipment. Essentially the remotely-sensed signal is a convolution of many-many function into a single function. To decompose the signal and restore the original data content one has to have the same amount of "orthogonal" or linearly independent receivers. Say, if you have a 64-bit memory bus emitting hard, you need somehow to collect the EM field from 64 angles/directions/polarizations whatever. Even then all signals will have nearly the same shape, which would result in ill-conditioned matrices, and solutions will be devastated by any instrumental noise (which ratio will be bad given the micro-volt level of signals). That's why I think that people who pushed this agenda were ignorant and dishonest, who were using the situation to milk military budgets.

Even if someone can get a full accurate trace of all memory traffic, it is impossible to make much sense of it, even if you have a full checked build and debug tables for the entire operating system.

In short, this seems to be a delirium form Cold War Era and utter nonsense. That's why there were no positive results for 40 years. Today much easier way is to put an app into a Samsung TV or any smartphone and record/transmit all voice over WiFi or always-on cellular network.

Comment: I read the question as trying to reconstruct the analog monitor signals to mirror the screen, not the original data.

Comment: Indeed, the exact words of the question are "mirroring of a CRT screen"  This responses either entirely ignores the question and substitutes a very different imagined one, or is based in gross ignorance of how raster-scanned analog video works, especially the fact that it's a minor variation on a scheme *designed* for broadcast integrity.  Even in a degraded case where the output was so degraded as to be only able to discern the number of characters in each word, that could be a huge leak - but given how repetitive the signal is, much more detail could likely be recovered.

Comment: @Transistor, the screen does contain data, doesn't it? And what was the reason to "mirror" the screen other than reconstruct the data?

Comment: The signal being monitored would be the analog raster signal which, if redisplayed, might be human readable but a difficult task for digital reverse engineering.  I suspect your downvotes (not by me) are as a result of your 64-bit memory bus, WiFi and cellular network references as all of these were more recent inventions.

Comment: @Transistor, okay, I see that my outburst is somewhat misplaced, although the question insinuates some applicability to modern days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am sorry that you appear to have misunderstood my question, as it implies nothing of the sort. It quite clearly asks how this was achieved 40 or so years ago.

Comment: @Greenonline, then your question is answered in first paragraph of my edited answer. The old CRT eavesdropping is maybe the only successful example, all due to its one-dimensional transmission protocol. For anything of more dimensions the eavesdropping fails miserably, due to considerations I explained (the other idea was to spy in printer ports CENTRONICS 8-bit, but I haven't heard of any "success stories").

Comment: @AliChen Hey, you gave me idea of reconstructing the printed text from the noise made by the matrix printers.

Comment: Oh no. https://spqr.eecs.umich.edu/courses/cs660sp11/papers/printers.pdf , https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/eavesdropping_o_3.html

Comment: @EugeneSh., I see, five crooks continue to milk public funds on the basis of paranoia started with CRT eavesdropping. Pathetic.

Comment: @AliChen As one who works in the field of information security I would not be that categorical about that. Even a slight advantage is often leading to the breaking of the most sophisticated security schemes.

Comment: In an age where neural networks and correlation attacks can deduce your private RSA key based on the sound of your laptop fans while encrypting, I would not be nearly so sanctimonious in pronouncing what security concerns are real and which aren't.

Comment: @mbrig *"based on the sound of your laptop fans while encrypting"* - this is a good joke! Thanks!

Comment: @AliChen the attack has already been demonstrated https://m.slashdot.org/story/195775

Comment: @mbrig, demonstrated? Read the abstract: *"...decryption of some chosen ciphertexts"..." They have to train their "neural network" (or whatever) for entire hour on "chosen" patterns. If you can "choose" patterns on target computer, why don't just send the key result over network, or just print it or say it? This is a crockery at best. Waste of public funds.

Comment: @AliChen Chosen-ciphertext attacks are pretty common in the field of cryptography. Its not *that* hard to get a target to operate on data you send it, depending on what you're attacking. Anyways, we're drifting off-topic so I'll drop it.

Comment: @AliChen Every attack is infeasible until it becomes feasible. The weaknesses in the published state of the art aren't reasons not to take precautions.